# How to configure opennebula for allowing a cluster private network to host images with public IPs

Tags: virtualization, nat, kvm-virtualization, opennebula

I am installing open nebula 3.4.1 for running virtual machines a (kvm based) cluster made of 5 computers: a front-end machine having 2 network interfaces and 4 slaves machines with a single network interface each.

The slaves of the cluster are connected to the front-end via a gigabit switch. The front-end uses the second network interface to connect to Internet. Such front-end is the only machine having a public IP. Indeed, the internal network exploits a class of private IPs (192.168.X.X). The front-end iptables has been already properly configured to forward and masquerade the connection from the slaves to the internet. Indeed, I am able to connect to ubuntu update sites directly from the slaves.

I also have a few public IPs that I would like to assign to certain Virtual Machines that will be run on the cluster.

Unfortunately, the slaves are connected to a private network, hence their virtual bridges, as far as I know, can receive only packets sent to IPs having the same network address/mask. As a consequence assigning them a public IP would result in a useless operation because the packets won't be properly routed to the physical machine hosting such a public IP.

Can you help me ? Do you have any suggestion ?

Regards,
  -- Patrizio